# iPhone SDK Quartz Glyph Drawing

Tags: iphone, objective-c, quartz-graphics, glyph

I am trying to render font glyphs at a specific point with some precision, and am having quite a bit of trouble with it.

To begin with, the Text Position Y value never changes, so I cannot get the glyph's height at all. For example, in the following code, the assertion always fires:

```
CGContextSelectFont(g, "Arial", 32.0f, kCGEncodingFontSpecific);

char c = 'A';
CGPoint pt = CGPointMake(400, 400);

CGContextSetTextDrawingMode(g, kCGTextInvisible);
CGContextSetTextPosition(g, pt.x, pt.y);
CGContextShowText(g, &c, 1);

CGPoint pt2 = CGContextGetTextPosition(g);
assert(pt2.y != pt.y);
```

I have tried to work around this using some hard-coded width-to-height ratios, assuming the glyphs scale linearly.  Note that the X value of the text position is updated correctly.

More importantly, however, is how the glyph renders in relation to the Text Position; some glyphs render with the Y value as the center of the glyph, some use the Y value as the top of the glyph, and others use the Y value as the bottom of the glyph.  I can't hard-code all this data and hope to get my app done any time this year.

Is there anything I am doing incorrectly in the drawing code above?  I can't find any reference in the Quartz docs related to vertical alignment, and am a little lost.

Answer (score 0):

From what I've gleamed this is a fairly complex task. I'd check out [zynga's LabelFont library](http://github.com/zynga/FontLabel) and either learn from their code or simply use the library. Especially have a look at the LabelFont class' `drawTextInRect:` method.

Comment: Thanks for the link.  I looked at this about a week ago, and it's doesn't really fit my needs; it's much more complex, and those methods in particular seem to be much more suited for dynamic sizing.  I don't need to glyphs to change to match a rectangle, I need a rectangle for the glyph!

Comment: Check out sizeWithZFont: in the FontLabelStringDrawing class.